# How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

How can I find the memory used on my Android application, programmatically?

I hope there is a way to do it. Plus, how do I get the free memory of the phone too?

Comment: Or if anyone want to know more about all this then please refer [http://elinux.org/Android_Memory_Usage](http://elinux.org/Android_Memory_Usage)

Comment: Manage your app's memory https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory

Comment: Use Android Profile build in extension in Android Studio that doesn't need any code.

Answer (score 1041, accepted):

Note that memory usage on modern operating systems like Linux is an *extremely* complicated and difficult to understand area.  In fact the chances of you actually correctly interpreting whatever numbers you get is extremely low.  (Pretty much every time I look at memory usage numbers with other engineers, there is always a long discussion about what they actually mean that only results in a vague conclusion.)

**Note: we now have much more extensive documentation on [Managing Your App's Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) that covers much of the material here and is more up-to-date with the state of Android.**

First thing is to probably read the last part of this article which has some discussion of how memory is managed on Android:

[Service API changes starting with Android 2.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html)

Now `ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()` is our highest-level API for looking at overall memory usage.  This is mostly there to help an application gauge how close the system is coming to having no more memory for background processes, thus needing to start killing needed processes like services.  For pure Java applications, this should be of little use, since the Java heap limit is there in part to avoid one app from being able to stress the system to this point.

Going lower-level, you can use the Debug API to get raw kernel-level information about memory usage: [android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getMemoryInfo)

Note starting with 2.0 there is also an API, `ActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo`, to get this information about another process: [ActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(int[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getProcessMemoryInfo(int[]))

This returns a low-level MemoryInfo structure with all of this data:

```
    /** The proportional set size for dalvik. */
    public int dalvikPss;
    /** The private dirty pages used by dalvik. */
    public int dalvikPrivateDirty;
    /** The shared dirty pages used by dalvik. */
    public int dalvikSharedDirty;

    /** The proportional set size for the native heap. */
    public int nativePss;
    /** The private dirty pages used by the native heap. */
    public int nativePrivateDirty;
    /** The shared dirty pages used by the native heap. */
    public int nativeSharedDirty;

    /** The proportional set size for everything else. */
    public int otherPss;
    /** The private dirty pages used by everything else. */
    public int otherPrivateDirty;
    /** The shared dirty pages used by everything else. */
    public int otherSharedDirty;
```

But as to what the difference is between `Pss`, `PrivateDirty`, and `SharedDirty`...  well now the fun begins.

A lot of memory in Android (and Linux systems in general) is actually shared across multiple processes.  So how much memory a processes uses is really not clear.  Add on top of that paging out to disk (let alone swap which we don't use on Android) and it is even less clear.

Thus if you were to take all of the physical RAM actually mapped in to each process, and add up all of the processes, you would probably end up with a number much greater than the actual total RAM.

The `Pss` number is a metric the kernel computes that takes into account memory sharing -- basically each page of RAM in a process is scaled by a ratio of the number of other processes also using that page.  This way you can (in theory) add up the pss across all processes to see the total RAM they are using, and compare pss between processes to get a rough idea of their relative weight.

The other interesting metric here is `PrivateDirty`, which is basically the amount of RAM inside the process that can not be paged to disk (it is not backed by the same data on disk), and is not shared with any other processes.  Another way to look at this is the RAM that will become available to the system when that process goes away (and probably quickly subsumed into caches and other uses of it).

That is pretty much the SDK APIs for this.  However there is more you can do as a developer with your device.

Using `adb`, there is a lot of information you can get about the memory use of a running system.  A common one is the command `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` which will spit out a bunch of information about the memory use of each Java process, containing the above info as well as a variety of other things.  You can also tack on the name or pid of a single process to see, for example `adb shell dumpsys meminfo system` give me the system process:

```
** MEMINFO in pid 890 [system] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:    10940     7047      N/A    17987
       allocated:     8943     5516      N/A    14459
            free:      336     1531      N/A     1867
           (Pss):     4585     9282    11916    25783
  (shared dirty):     2184     3596      916     6696
    (priv dirty):     4504     5956     7456    17916

 Objects
           Views:      149        ViewRoots:        4
     AppContexts:       13       Activities:        0
          Assets:        4    AssetManagers:        4
   Local Binders:      141    Proxy Binders:      158
Death Recipients:       49
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
            heap:      205          dbFiles:        0
       numPagers:        0   inactivePageKB:        0
    activePageKB:        0
```

The top section is the main one, where `size` is the total size in address space of a particular heap, `allocated` is the kb of actual allocations that heap thinks it has, `free` is the remaining kb free the heap has for additional allocations, and `pss` and `priv dirty` are the same as discussed before specific to pages associated with each of the heaps.

If you just want to look at memory usage across all processes, you can use the command `adb shell procrank`.  Output of this on the same system looks like:

```
  PID      Vss      Rss      Pss      Uss  cmdline
  890   84456K   48668K   25850K   21284K  system_server
 1231   50748K   39088K   17587K   13792K  com.android.launcher2
  947   34488K   28528K   10834K    9308K  com.android.wallpaper
  987   26964K   26956K    8751K    7308K  com.google.process.gapps
  954   24300K   24296K    6249K    4824K  com.android.phone
  948   23020K   23016K    5864K    4748K  com.android.inputmethod.latin
  888   25728K   25724K    5774K    3668K  zygote
  977   24100K   24096K    5667K    4340K  android.process.acore
...
   59     336K     332K      99K      92K  /system/bin/installd
   60     396K     392K      93K      84K  /system/bin/keystore
   51     280K     276K      74K      68K  /system/bin/servicemanager
   54     256K     252K      69K      64K  /system/bin/debuggerd
```

Here the `Vss` and `Rss` columns are basically noise (these are the straight-forward address space and RAM usage of a process, where if you add up the RAM usage across processes you get an ridiculously large number).

`Pss` is as we've seen before, and `Uss` is `Priv Dirty`.

Interesting thing to note here: `Pss` and `Uss` are slightly (or more than slightly) different than what we saw in `meminfo`.  Why is that?  Well procrank uses a different kernel mechanism to collect its data than `meminfo` does, and they give slightly different results.  Why is that?  Honestly I haven't a clue.  I believe `procrank` may be the more accurate one...  but really, this just leave the point: "take any memory info you get with a grain of salt; often a very large grain."

Finally there is the command `adb shell cat /proc/meminfo` that gives a summary of the overall memory usage of the system.  There is a lot of data here, only the first few numbers worth discussing (and the remaining ones understood by few people, and my questions of those few people about them often resulting in conflicting explanations):

```
MemTotal:         395144 kB
MemFree:          184936 kB
Buffers:             880 kB
Cached:            84104 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
```

`MemTotal` is the total amount of memory available to the kernel and user space (often less than the actual physical RAM of the device, since some of that RAM is needed for the radio, DMA buffers, etc).

`MemFree` is the amount of RAM that is not being used at all.  The number you see here is very high; typically on an Android system this would be only a few MB, since we try to use available memory to keep processes running

`Cached` is the RAM being used for filesystem caches and other such things.  Typical systems will need to have 20MB or so for this to avoid getting into bad paging states; the Android out of memory killer is tuned for a particular system to make sure that background processes are killed before the cached RAM is consumed too much by them to result in such paging.

Answer (score 84):

Yes, you can get memory info programmatically and decide whether to do memory intensive work.

Get VM Heap Size by calling:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

Get Allocated VM Memory by calling:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Get VM Heap Size Limit by calling:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

Get Native Allocated Memory by calling:

```
Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
```

I made an app to figure out the OutOfMemoryError behavior and monitor memory usage.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.coocood.oomresearch

You can get the source code at
https://github.com/coocood/oom-research

Comment: Does this runtime will return memory usage by current process or overall system heap ?

Comment: @mahemadhi from the JavaDoc of totalMemory() method "Returns the total amount of memory which is available to the running program"

Comment: This is not a correct answer to the question. The answer is not about a specific application.

Answer (score 52):

This is a work in progress, but this is what I don't understand:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.availMem " + memoryInfo.availMem + "\n" );
Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.lowMemory " + memoryInfo.lowMemory + "\n" );
Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.threshold " + memoryInfo.threshold + "\n" );

List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

Map<Integer, String> pidMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses)
{
    pidMap.put(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
}

Collection<Integer> keys = pidMap.keySet();

for(int key : keys)
{
    int pids[] = new int[1];
    pids[0] = key;
    android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
    for(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo pidMemoryInfo: memoryInfoArray)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("** MEMINFO in pid %d [%s] **\n",pids[0],pidMap.get(pids[0])));
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty() + "\n");
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss() + "\n");
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Why isn't the PID mapped to the result in activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo()?  Clearly you want to make the resulting data meaningful, so why has Google made it so difficult to correlate the results?  The current system doesn't even work well if I want to process the entire memory usage since the returned result is an array of android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo objects, but none of those objects actually tell you what pids they are associated with.  If you simply pass in an array of all pids, you will have no way to understand the results.  As I understand it's use, it makes it meaningless to pass in more than one pid at a time, and then if that's the case, why make it so that activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo() only takes an int array?

Comment: They're likely in the same order as the input array.

Comment: That seems like a very non-intuitive way to do things.  Yes, that probably is the case, but how is that in any way OOP?

Comment: The API was designed for efficiency, not ease of use or simplicity.  This is just not something that 99% of apps should ever touch, so efficiency is the most important design goal.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm trying to write an internal tool to track memory usage for one or more of the applications we're writing. As a result, I'm looking for a way to do this monitoring while impacting the other processes the least, but still being as detailed with the results as possible (post-processing). Iterating over the processes, and then making calls for each process seems to be inefficient, assuming there is some overhead for each .getProcessMemoryInfo call. If the returned array is guaranteed to be in the same order as the call, I'll process the results blindly and just assume parity.

Comment: This is a minor issue, but for Log, it isn't necessary to add a linefeed, that is handled for you.

Comment: to get it to compile I had to add a bit to the code:  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
  activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

Comment: also with api 16 you might want total memory with the following: Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.totalMem" + memoryInfo.totalMem+ "\n" );

Comment: Note regarding efficiency -- simply *collecting* the PSS data is far far more expensive than doing an additional IPC to find out information about the process (though to be clear, the API is designed so you don't need to do that, the results are returned in the same order as the requested PIDs).  If you are doing something where efficiency is a concern, and you are worried about the cost of a few IPCs, you actually have much larger problems in the cost of getting that memory data in the first place.

Answer (score 24):

Hackbod's is one of the best answers on Stack Overflow. It throws light on a very obscure subject. It helped me a lot.

Another really helpful resource is this must-see video: [Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

---

**UPDATE:**

Process Stats, a service to discover how your app manages memory explained at the blog post *[Process Stats: Understanding How Your App Uses RAM](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/process-stats-understanding-how-your.html)* by Dianne Hackborn:

Answer (score 18):

Android Studio 0.8.10+ has introduced an incredibly useful tool called [Memory Monitor](https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html).

[image]

What it's good for:

> - Showing available and used memory in a graph, and garbage collection
>     events over time.
> - Quickly testing whether app slowness might be
>     related to excessive garbage collection events.
> - Quickly testing
>     whether app crashes may be related to running out of memory.

[image]

Figure 1. Forcing a GC (Garbage Collection) event on Android Memory Monitor

You can have plenty good information on your app's RAM real-time consumption by using it.

Answer (score 17):

1) I guess not, at least not from Java.
2)

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
Log.i("memory free", "" + mi.availMem);
```

Comment: change to (ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);) instead of (ActivityManager activityManager = = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);)

Answer (score 11):

We found out that all the standard ways of getting the total memory of the current process have some issues.

- **`Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`**: returns JVM memory only
- **`ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()`**, **`Process.getFreeMemory()`** and anything else based on **`/proc/meminfo`** - returns memory info about all the processes combined (e.g. [android_util_Process.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_util_Process.cpp))
- **`Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`** - uses `mallinfo()` which return information about memory allocations performed by `malloc()` and related functions only (see [android_os_Debug.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_os_Debug.cpp))
- **`Debug.getMemoryInfo()`** - does the job but it's too slow. It takes about **200ms** on **Nexus 6** for a single call. The performance overhead makes this function useless for us as we call it regularly and every call is quite noticeable (see [android_os_Debug.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_os_Debug.cpp))
- **`ActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(int[])`** - calls `Debug.getMemoryInfo()` internally (see [ActivityManagerService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java))

Finally, we ended up using the following code:

```cs
const long pageSize = 4 * 1024; //`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`
string stats = File.ReadAllText("/proc/self/statm");
var statsArr = stats.Split(new [] {' ', '\t', '\n'}, 3);

if( statsArr.Length < 2 )
    throw new Exception("Parsing error of /proc/self/statm: " + stats);

return long.Parse(statsArr[1]) * pageSize;
```

It returns **VmRSS** metric. You can find more details about it here: [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size), [two](http://serverfault.com/a/559563) and [three](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

---

**P.S.** I noticed that the theme still has a lack of an actual and simple code snippet of how to *estimate* the private memory usage of the process if the performance isn't a critical requirement:

```java
Debug.MemoryInfo memInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
long res = memInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
    res += memInfo.getTotalPrivateClean(); 

return res * 1024L;
```

Answer (score 2):

In android studio 3.0 they have introduced android-profiler to help you to understand how your app uses CPU, memory, network, and battery resources.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got confused while reading answers, So I decided to read docs.
OK, Let's do it:

### Native heap memory usage

You can get native heap memory size of the device using [Debug](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug) object:

```
long nativeTotal = Debug.getNativeHeapSize();
long nativeFree = Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize();
long nativeAllocated = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
long nativeUsed = nativeTotal - nativeFree;
```

Note: `nativeUsed` and `nativeAllocated` have the same value.

### Runtime memory usage

Memory usage using [Runtime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime) object of the application, Every application has a runtime object to access its interface:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long runtimeMax = runtime.maxMemory();
long runtimeTotal = runtime.totalMemory();
long runtimeFree = runtime.freeMemory();
long runtimeUsed = runtimeTotal - runtimeFree;
```

### System memory usage

You can get the memory usage of the system using [ActivityManager.MemoryInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo) object:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
long systemTotal = memoryInfo.totalMem;
long systemFree = memoryInfo.availMem;
long systemUsed = systemTotal - systemFree;
```

### Proc memory usage

Another way to read the memory usage of the system is by parsing the contents of the [/proc/meminfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251290) file in linux.

```
RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher totalMatcher = pattern.matcher(reader.readLine());
totalMatcher.find();
long procTotal = Long.parseLong(totalMatcher.group(1)) * 1024L; // KB to B
Matcher freeMatcher = pattern.matcher(reader.readLine());
freeMatcher.find();
long procFree = Long.parseLong(freeMatcher.group(1)) * 1024L; // KB to B
long procUsed = procTotal - procFree;
```

---

OK, I am still confused. But this was all the ways you can get the memory usage. **LOG THEM ALL TO DEBUG YOUR APPLICATION**!!!

I also provided a link for each of them to read their usage and information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answer above which will definitely help you but *(after 2 days of afford and research on adb memory tools)* I think i can help with my **opinion** too.

As  [Hackbod says : **Thus if you were to take all of the physical RAM actually mapped in to each process, and add up all of the processes, you would probably end up with a number much greater than the actual total RAM.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299813/2553431)  so there is no way you can get exact amount of memory per process.

*But you can get close to it by some logic..and I will tell how..*

> There are some API like `android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo` and `ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()` mentioned above which you already might have being read about and used but I will talk about other way

So firstly you need to be a root user to get it work. Get into console with root privilege by executing `su` in process and get its `output and input stream`. Then pass `id\n` *(enter)* in ouputstream and write it to process output, If will get an inputstream containing `uid=0`, **you are root user.**

*Now here is the logic which you will use in above process*

When you get ouputstream of process **pass you command (procrank, dumpsys meminfo etc...) with `\n` instead of id** and get its `inputstream` and read, store the stream in bytes[ ] ,char[ ] etc.. use **raw** data..and you are done!!!!!

permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST"/>
```

Check if you are root user :

```
// su command to get root access
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");         
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = 
                           new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream dataInputStream = 
                           new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
if (dataInputStream != null && dataOutputStream != null) {
   // write id to console with enter
   dataOutputStream.writeBytes("id\n");                   
   dataOutputStream.flush();
   String Uid = dataInputStream.readLine();
   // read output and check if uid is there
   if (Uid.contains("uid=0")) {                           
      // you are root user
   } 
}
```

Execute your command with `su`

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");         
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = 
                           new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
if (dataOutputStream != null) {
 // adb command
 dataOutputStream.writeBytes("procrank\n");             
 dataOutputStream.flush();
 BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = 
                     new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
 // this is important as it takes times to return to next line so wait
 // else you with get empty bytes in buffered stream 
 try {
       Thread.sleep(10000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {                     
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
 // read buffered stream into byte,char etc.
 byte[] bff = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
 bufferedInputStream.read(bff);
 bufferedInputStream.close();
 }
}
```

logcat :
[image: result]

> **You get a raw data in a single string from console instead of in some instance from any API,which is complex to store as you will need to separate it manually**.

*This is just a try, please suggest me if I missed something*